Angular and ASP.NET Core 8 on IIS not loading Angular pages
I've created a solution using the new Angular and ASP.NET Core 8 template.
This template creates two projects. One containing the Angular site (project.client), and the other containing all the ASP.NET Core logic and APIs that the Angular site uses (project.server).
I'm now trying to publish to IIS. The template automatically adds the Angular project (project.client) as a dependency to the API project (project.server).

Visual Studio offers no option to Publish the client project.
When I publish the server project, the output includes all the angular files.
When adding the output to IIS, the API (project.server) appears to function correctly.
These are at https://serveraddress/api/ as expected.
However, navigating to https://serveraddress does not return any of the Angular files.
I just receive an Error 404.
How do I deploy projects created by the new template?
Alternatively, how do I debug or view logs on what is happening within IIS when accessing the root URL is attempted?

I resolved the issue manually, but would like to know how to fix the deployment so that it works automatically. To fix it, I had to manually move the files from the output wwwroot/browser directory up one level to the wwwroot directory.

This is a known issue due to the Angular output folder in v17 now has an additional browser folder in the hierarchy (the reasoning is that SSR related output would go in a sibling server folder). See this case for more details.
Then the workarounds we could try are:

change the WebRootPath, use code below to replace var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions()
{
WebRootPath = "wwwroot/browser"
});

change <BuildOutputFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist\angularapp1.client\</BuildOutputFolder> with <BuildOutputFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\dist\angularapp1.client\browser</BuildOutputFolder>, we can double click the appname.client to change this property.

I test both of the workaround and they all worked. In the meantime, that case mentioned this is currently being investigated and the fix is available in the  preview version of VS 2022.
